# div duplicate on enter

Tags: html, css

I have a div inside my editable container and when I press enter the div duplicate and I end up have two divs one on the top of the other.
the container have contenteditable as true, this might be causing this issue.
but is there anyway i can prevent this

```
<div class="singlediv"></div>
```

with the css

```
.singlediv {
    border-color: rgb(155, 196, 243);
    border: dotted 1px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-height: 75px;
}
```

[code here](https://codepen.io/KhAzZaKa/pen/wvMrZJN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a function like following in your js :-

```
const handleEnter=(e)=>{
if(e.keyCode===13)
{
e.preventDefault();
}
}
```

And your html will be-

```
  <div contenteditable="true" onkeypress="handleEnter(event)">
        <div class="singlediv"></div>
    </div>
```

The function `handleEnter` ensures to prevent the the default behaviour when pressing enter button on a div with `.contentEditable` attribute. The key code for `Enter key` is 13.

This is more of a hack. If you can prevent having the inner div, then do so.

Answer (score 2):

That's really simple, if you make `contenteditable` with a div withing then you press enter an another div will be created. This code run corretly :

```css
 .singlediv {
            border-color: rgb(155, 196, 243);
            border: dotted 1px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            min-height: 75px;
        }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="singlediv"></div>
```